# Check a table against another table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a list of people that I got from table 1.

```
SELECT UA.user FROM UserAcct UA
```

I have another table that I need to check against to make sure that the user is not listed in table 2.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountsLog AL ON AL.user = UA.user
```

Ultimately what I am trying to do is make sure that people from table 1 have performed an action on table 2, otherwise their name will be returned. Performing this action will cause their name to show up in table 2.  Any help here is greatly appreciated.  I am happy to try and elaborate further if this isn't enough information.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `WHERE AL.User IS NULL` in your join or try `WHERE EXISTS (select...)`

Comment: So what is wrong with ? What exactly want yo do ? Could you make it clear?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Yes, yes I do... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do a left outer join to find records in TABLE A that are not in table B, simply look for NULLs.

So when you LEFT OUTER JOIN the tables on ON AL.user = UA.user, you can then find the missing records with the clause:

```
WHERE AL.user IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want Anything from `User` that not exists in `AccountsLog`, I think you're on the right track

```
SELECT UA.user FROM UserAcct UA
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountsLog AL ON UA.user = AL.user
WHER AL.User is null -- this will give you anything that is on user and not in accountslog
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This will give the users only on UA and not on AL

```
SELECT UA.user FROM UserAcct UA
MINUS
SELECT AL.user FROM AccountsLog AL
```

Edit:- For SQL server use EXCEPT instead of MINUS (Supported by Oracle)

Comment: `MINUS` is an Oracle specific operator. In the SQL standard (and SQL Server) that would be `EXCEPT`

Comment: Oh yeah.. I did not see its sql server. Then it should be except and not minus

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQL supports it, try using Not Exists.  [Subqueries with NOT EXISTS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  I've found it is faster than "left outer joins and filtering for null values".